Decimal to binary using stack but not sure how the input should be a stack itself
I do not understand the concept of how I can pop an integer from a stack and convert it into binary.
I successfully created a program that can take in an integer and convert it to binary by pushing it into an array using stack but I am not sure how I can make my input a stack itself where I can pop each integer in a stack and then push them into an array to change it into binary.
class ArrayStack: #puts in and removes from the top only
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = [ ]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)
    
    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self._data) == 0
    
    def push(self, e):
        self._data.append(e)

    def top(self):
        if self.is_empty( ):
            raise Exception("No Elements in Stack")
        return self._data[-1]
    
    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty( ):
            raise Exception("No Elements in Stack")
        return self._data.pop() 
    

def decToBin(num):
    stack = ArrayStack()
    while num > 0:
        remainder = num % 2
        stack.push(remainder)
        num = num // 2

    _str = ''
    while not stack.is_empty():
        Bin = stack.pop()
        _str = _str + str(Bin)
    return int(_str)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(decToBin(65536))


Why are you bothering to store the digits in a stack?  What is the purpose?

@JohnGordon Apparently to reverse the bits for output.

"how I can make my input a stack itself where I can pop each integer in a stack and then push them into an array to change it into binary.": you lost me. What is it that you want as output? What is the problem?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you just want to present an integer in its base 2 form then take a look at the b format specifier or the built-in bin() function. Or is this just an exercise in using a "stack" for no good reason?

It looks like you thought of using a stack to solve a problem of reversed order: your first loop gets the bits in the order from least-significant to most-significant, while the easiest is to build the result number with its digits from most-significant to least-significant. I guess you then thought of a stack...
You don't need a stack for that.
Instead, keep track of the power-of-10 that you want the current bit from the input to represent. For example, if the input is eleven, which in binary is 1011, then the translation is as follows:
    1011    power
    │││└─ * 1    =    1
    ││└── * 10   =   10   
    │└─── * 100  =    0
    └──── * 1000 = 1000
                   ────── +
                   1011

Your first loop will visit the bits from right-to-left, i.e. from top-to-bottom if we look at the right side of this visualisation. As you will notice, you'll just need that power to be kept updated in your first loop and add it to the result when the current bit is 1.
Not your question, but:

I find the name decToBin confusing. There is nothing decimal about the input. The input is an integer. How you represent that is another thing, but it is not inherently a decimal integer. I would suggest a better name, like maybe bitsToPowersOf10:

Your solution converts numbers to strings (with str()) and back to number (with int()). But if you allow for involving strings in the process, then you don't need loops and could just have used this one-liner in your function:
return int(bin(num)[2:])

But I guess the purpose of the exercise is to achieve it without any conversion to string.


Here is how the schema given above can be implemented:
def bitsToPowersOf10(num):
    result = 0
    power_of_10 = 1
    while num > 0:
        if num % 2:
            result += power_of_10
        power_of_10 *= 10  # The essence!
        num //= 2
    return result
    
print(bitsToPowersOf10(11))  # 1011


Thank you so much for the idea, it was quite useful. Although would love to not use a stack but using it is part of the exercise? Is there any way to have the numbers in the stack initially, and then pop it out to become a integer?

What exactly is said in the exercise? Can you quote it?

here is what I was told to do. " the illustration provided suggests that the number is a stack of individual digits (6, 5, 5, 3, 6). This means that the decimal order is still observed (60000 + 5000 + 500 + 30 + 6) because it will be difficult to get the correct answer if each digit is only treated individually without its place value. While this may be cumbersome, this is still the decimal representation of the number.the computations should lead to a stack of either 0s or 1s which you can push every time division by two happens, then pop when you print"

This looks like a different task. It speaks of decimal digits like 6, 5, 5, 3, 6. But those play no role in what you have implemented. I'm lost. Can you quote the complete assignment and add examples of input/output. I think you may have misunderstood the assignment, but I cannot tell from the snippet you have quoted what the assignment is.
